# How to make line from SHP file thicker?

Tags: edit-mode, sculpting

I am new to blender and working with BlenderGIS and geodata. After creating contours lines in QGIS and exporting them as SHP file I imported them with the BlenderGIS plugin.

There is 1 layer for contour lines every 10m and another for contour lines every 50m.
I want to be able to differenciate them. I would like to make the 50m lines thicker and if possible anotate them with the right altitude.

[image]

What I tried:

- styling the lines in QGIS but SHP doesn't export styling
- color the lines but it is not visible
- messed around with grease pencil and modifiers but I don't really know what I am doing.

Comment: You can try adding a skin modifier. Might choke your pc if there are two many vertices though. Or convert to curve and add a bevel

Comment: The skin modifier gives the result that I am looking for but only for the first bottom contour line. I ended up converting it to a curve and adding a bevel of 0.5m. Thank you.